# HTML <br> and innerHTML

Tags: javascript, dom

I have some content like this

```
var p =  

 I myself
 Abhimanyu Singh
 Yadav
```

when I m trying to insert into as `innerHTML` to some `div` the whole content appears in one line. I'm using `<pre>` tag to avoid this problem. But need some appropriate solution.

Comment: Can I understand your question as "When inserting multi-line text via Javascript it displays in one line. How can I insert `<br>` tags instead?"

Comment: Can you please post the code for this?

Comment: I don't think its related to question formatting.

Answer (score 5):

You can [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) the new line characters with [html BR](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#edef-BR) elements (`<br />`):

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = p.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var p = "i myself<br />Abhimanyu Singh<br />Yadav";
```

updated to make andrew happy. a still non-semantic answer that is more semantic.

Comment: Totally non-semantic. A terrible idea. It will style as a paragraph break instead of a line-break.

Comment: yes, it appears this OP is worried about semantics, first off, as he is trying to insert line breaks in completely random places. when a user asks something ridiculous like this, i give an answer that works. if he wants to replace the `<p>` tags w/`<br />` tags, whatever